# FIWARE Orion/MongoDB Performance on AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fiware, fiware-orion

I seem to be having real issues trying to get performance anywhere near that stated in the docs (~700 - 2000 tps with a VM of: 2 vCPUs 4GB RAM). I have tried on a local VM, a local machine and a few AWS VMs and I can't get anywhere close. - The maximum I have achieved is 80 tps on an AWS VM.

I have tried changing the -dbPoolSize and the -reqPoolSize for orion and playing with ulimit to set it to that suggested by MongoDB - but everything I change doesn't seem to get me anywhere close.

I have set indexes on the _id.id, _id.type and _id.servicePath as suggested in the docs - the latter of which gave me an increase from 40 tps to 80 tps.

Are there any config options for Orion or Mongo that I should be setting away from the default which will get me any closer? Are there any other tips for performance? The link in the docs to the test scripts doesn't work so I haven't been able to see the examples.

I have created my own test scripts using Node.js and I have tested update and queries using a variable amount of concurrent connections and between 1 and 2 load injectors.

From looking at the output from "top" the load is with Mongo as it almost maxes out the CPU but adding more cores to the VM doesn't change the stats. The VM has 7.5GB or 15GB of RAM so mongo should be able to put all the data into memory for blazing fast performance?

I have used mongostat to see that the connections from orion to mongo change with the -dbPoolSize option, but this doesn't yield any better performance.

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

I have tried using CentOS 6.5 and 6.7 with Orion 0.25 and 0.26 and MongoDB 2.6 with ~500,000 entities

My test scripts and data are [on GitHub](https://github.com/web-bert/orion-tester)

I have only tested without subscriptions so far, but I have scripts ready to test with subscriptions - but I wanted to get a good baseline before adding subscriptions.

My data is modeled around parking spaces in the UK countries their regions and their outcodes (first part of the postcode). This is using servicePaths to split them down to parking lot in an outcode.

Here is a [gist with the requests and mongo shell output](https://gist.github.com/web-bert/32d506a5e089a78ab83a)

Comment: Can you edit the post to add some details on the kind of operations used to stress CB, please? A "template" of the update and query operation you are using would be ok.

Comment: In addition, could you edit the post to clarify if, appart of the entities set, do you have subscriptions, please?

Comment: Hi fgalan, I have updated the question and added a link to my test scripts and data.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the "naked request" that your code send to Orion, i.e. request line (verb + URL) + HTTP headers + payload (if applicable). Inferring such information from the code itself would be hard without looking it in detail (in addition, I'm not an expert in JavaScript). I'm meaning something like this: https://gist.github.com/fgalan/ff035ae09d98b0842771

Comment: In addition, assuming that your entities have a regular shape (i.e. all them with the same attributes) it would be great if you could add to the question post a "model entity", e.g. the output of `db.entities.findOne()` at mongo shell.

Comment: thanks @fgalan I have added a link to a gist with the requested info

Answer (score 0):

Performance is a complex topic which depends on many factor (deployment setup of Orion and MongoDB, startup configuration of Orion and MongoDB, hardware profile in the systems hosting the processes, network communications, overprovisioning level in the case of virtualization, injected load, etc.) so there isn't any general answer to deal with this kind of problems. However, I'd try to provide some hints and recommendations that I hope may help.

Regarding versions, Orion 0.26.0 (or 0.26.1) is recommended over 0.25.0. We have included a [lot of improvements](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/releases/tag/0.26.0) related with performance in Orion 0.26.0. Regarding MongoDB, we have also found that [3.0 could be much better than 2.6](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/perf_tuning/index.html#mongodb-version), specially in update intensive scenarios.

Having said that, first of all you should locate the bottleneck. Useful tools to do this are [top](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm), [mongostat](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/) and [mongotop](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongotop/). It could be either Orion, MongoDB or the network connecting them. If the bottleneck is CB, maybe the performance tuning hints provided in [this document may help](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/perf_tuning/index.html). Slow queries information in MongoDB could be also pointing to bottlenecks at Orion. If the bottleneck is MongoDB, taking into account the large number of entities you have (500,000) maybe you should consider to implement [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-shards/). If the bottleneck is the network, colocation both Orion and MongoDB may help.

Finally, some things you can also try in order to get more insight into the problem:

- Run some tests outside AWS (i.e. virtual machines in local premises) to compare. I don't know too much about the overprovising policy in AWS but based in my previous experiences with other cloud providers the VM overprovisioning (specially if it varies along time) could impact in performance.
- Analyze if the peformance is related with the number of entities. E.g. run test with 500, 5,000, 50,000 and 500,000 entities and get the performance figure in each case.
- Analyze if the performance is related with the usage of servicePath, e.g. put all the 500,000 entities in the default service path `/` (moving the current content of the servicePath to another place, e.g. an entity attribute or part of the entity ID string) and test. Currently Orion uses a regex to filter for servicePath and that could be slow.

Comment: Regarding the last bullet, I'd be specially interested in the result, given that if it is confirmed is a problem, Orion query strategy for servicePath should change. Please @graham-v, keep posting about your progress!

Comment: Having enabled some stats in Orion, is [this JSON](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e8751243ade89ccd8a00) telling me that 10 seconds was spend waiting for the internal "mongoBackend" module - i.e. mongo is not the bottleneck?

Comment: I have also tested the network between my local box and the VM (using my current scripts) and I can easily get ~3000 rps from a simple HTTP server. So I think I can rule out the network and my scripts as they can inject enough load and the network can handle it.

Comment: It could be due to a slow query at the DB. In order to keep researching on this, next step would be to isolate the query that runs at DB (running CB with `-logLevel INFO` would so it just after `Database Operation Successful` upon sending the request at the REST API). In addition, I'd probably need a dump of the `orion` database. Could it be possible to have it (not sure about the confidentiality/sensibility of such data)? We can rely in private chanels to pass the dump is you prefer so.

Comment: In the end I updated to 0.26.1 and used "-reqMutexPolicy none -dbPoolSize 100" and this has put the bottleneck with mongodb instead of Orion. So I think this is a good step forward. However, mongo does seem to be working really hard to fulfil the queries: on a c3.8xlarge machine (32 cores, 60GB RAM) I have only managed to get ~250 tps when I would expect this to be in the 1000's on that kind of hardware? It is good to see the CPU usage with top now maxes out all cores though, previously it would get to ~100% now it gets to (num of cores)*100% - on a 16 core machine I'm seeing 1600% utilisation

Comment: None of the data is confidential as this is just a test project with mock data. If you want to run the test scripts yourself all you need is a machine with Node.js on it (and a machine with Orion of course), then you can clone my repo above and run through the couple of [steps in the readme](https://github.com/web-bert/orion-tester#setup-scripts) to create the dataset and then run the queryEntities.js script.